# Firebase Cloud Functions + Puppeteer can't take screenshot of emoji

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, puppeteer

I'm trying to take screenshot of a page with emoji by puppeteer on Firebase Cloud Functions, but emoji doesn't show up correctly in the saved screenshot.

It seems Puppeteer on Cloud Functions doesn't have emoji font, so I tried to set emoji font via @font-face, but I can't.

here is my cloud functions code.
I call the screenshot function inside of some HTTPS Cloud Functions.

```js
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
admin.initializeApp();
const storage = admin.storage();
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

function screenshot() {
    (async () => {
      const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true, args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'] });
      const page = await browser.newPage();
      await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36');
      await page.evaluate(() => {
        const style = document.createElement('style')
        style.textContent = `
        @font-face {
          font-family: "emoji";
          src:local("Noto Color Emoji"),
              url("./NotoColorEmoji.ttf");
        };
        @font-face {
          font-family: 'Noto Sans JP';
          font-style: normal;
          font-weight: 400;
            src: local("Noto Sans CJK JP"),
              url(//fonts.gstatic.com/ea/notosansjp/v5/NotoSansJP-Regular.woff2) format('woff2'),
              url(//fonts.gstatic.com/ea/notosansjp/v5/NotoSansJP-Regular.woff) format('woff'),
              url(//fonts.gstatic.com/ea/notosansjp/v5/NotoSansJP-Regular.otf) format('opentype');
        };
        body, svg{ font-family: "Noto Sans JP", "emoji", sans-serif; };`
        document.head.appendChild(style);
        document.body.style.fontFamily = "'Noto Sans JP', 'emoji' , sans-serif";
      })
      await page.waitFor(5000); // waiting time to load font
      await page.goto("https://getemoji.com/"); //go to emoji page
      await page.screenshot({
        path: '/tmp/screenshot.png',
        omitBackground: true,
      })
      .then(() => {
        // upload screenshot to firebase storage
        storage.bucket('bucketName').upload('/tmp/screenshot.png')
        .then(() => {
          console.log("success");
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
      });
    })();
}
```

and here is the result screenshot:
[screenshot.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2HI0.png)

Comment: Having the same issue. Works fine locally with `@font-face`

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: Same issue when using playwright on Firebase Functions 2nd gen.